# Way to import templates to Angular 6

Tags: angular

I have (Html + css + js) template and I want to convert this template to fit in Angular 6. What is the best way to do that?

Some people said that we have to include all css assets to styles in cli and the js assets to scripts. But I think js files will conflict with Angular. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

HTML and CSS are fine when put in cli .
but the js files are not. so you have to convert them to ts and insert accordingly.

For example i have a Breadcrumb in my SPA and i have it isolated in to one component and use it in spa main

template

```
 <ng-template ngFor let-breadcrumb [ngForOf]="breadcrumbs" let-last = last>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item"
        *ngIf="breadcrumb.label.title&&breadcrumb.url.substring(breadcrumb.url.length-1) == '/'||breadcrumb.label.title&&last"
        [ngClass]="{active: last}">
      <a *ngIf="!last" [routerLink]="breadcrumb.url">{{breadcrumb.label.title}}</a>
      <span *ngIf="last" [routerLink]="breadcrumb.url">{{breadcrumb.label.title}}</span>
    </li>
  </ng-template>`
}
```

and my TS file

```
export class BreadcrumbsComponent {
  breadcrumbs: Array<Object>;
  constructor(
    public router: Router,
    public route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {
    this.router.events.pipe(filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)).subscribe((event) => {
      this.breadcrumbs = [];

      let currentRoute = this.route.root,
      url = '';
      do {
        const childrenRoutes = currentRoute.children;
        currentRoute = null;
        childrenRoutes.forEach(route => {
          if (route.outlet === 'primary') {
            const routeSnapshot = route.snapshot;
            //console.log("route.snapshot.data ", route.snapshot.data);
            console.log("url" + url);
            url += '/' + routeSnapshot.url.map(segment => segment.path).join('/');
            this.breadcrumbs.push({
              label: route.snapshot.data,
              url:   url
            });
            currentRoute = route;
          }
        });
      } while (currentRoute);
    });
  }
}
```